# How to calculate mAP with a tensorflow model object detection?

Tags: tensorflow2.0

Anyone know how to calculate the mAP coco dataset for every class with my own tensorflow object detection model?

I edit one model to do one new operation to increase the object detection. In the output i have one array with the roi coordinates detections, the score and the class.

I have finding how to measure the mAP but i dont find anything to do that. I am working with tensorflow object detection and i want to evaluate the mAP using coco dataset.

Comment: What have you done so far? Where is your code. Where are you stuck?

Comment: I update the comment, now i am working with tensorflow object detection . I implemented one function to increase the detections and i need to evaluate the map but i dont find anything of these on internet.

Comment: Have you gone through the official documentation for "tensorflow v2" object-detection-api? The API by-default evaluates with cocodataset but you will have to install. Check the docs https://tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/training.html

Comment: The problem is that my model is centernet and i create a function to increase the detections but i dont know how to evaluate the mAP. I see the url but i think that i cant do it

Comment: What have you done so far? Share the piece of code. "How to do this" is not what stackoverflow.com/about is